# Sigma.js learning and examples

Tags: javascript, java, sigma.js

I would like to discover sigma.js so I might use it in a project.
I know already a little of d3 but through searching on the internet people
mention that sigma is better for graphs and in my case , for example in graph 
databases sigma might be better. But I searched and I couldn't find a lot documentation about sigma or any tutorials. Even the examples in jacomy's website doesn't exist. Could someone advice me on where to start in order to learn sigma.js?

Answer (score 1):

I have found some tutorials on the GitHub of the Project:

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/examples

Also in this website:

http://thewhyaxis.info/hairball/

And it's official page:

http://sigmajs.org/

---

For example as you can see here from the official tutorials page , a simple example could be the below:

For the **Data**:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "And a last one",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      "size": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n0"
    }
  ]
}
```

For **html**:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #container {
        max-width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="sigma.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      sigma.parsers.json('data.json', {
        container: 'container',
        settings: {
          defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
        }
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Which will result to:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty nice and simple example : [Github example](https://github.com/tweetegy/sigmajs_example)

and the wiki of the sigma.js github repository is also well detailed : [Sigma.js – Wiki](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki)